# Python library for complex web scraping?

Tags: html, python, scraping

My goal is to interact with a website (Portfolio123.com) and download financial study results.

To get to the content means logging in, then clicking buttons and/or filling forms. Some of these buttons load using 'body onload'. The resulting HTML often contains a link to a downloadable Excel file which is generated specifically for the logged in user.

Therefore some of the requirements are:

- Cookies.
- Wait for "body onload".
- Find (and click) an element by id, name or XPath.
- Import a given table from HTML.
- Run JavaScript.
- Download to file and/or to object.

Some preliminary choices that I have come up with so far:

- **Selenium**.
- **RoboBrowser**. EDIT: Blends Requests and BeautifulSoup. Won't click JavaScript buttons.
- **Mechanize** + **ExecJS**. EDIT: Mechanize didn't work for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655568/login-to-a-website-using-python-and-mechanize
- **Scrapy**. This seems like it aims at web crawling. But will it do the job well?
- **PythonWebKit**. This looked promising but when I tried installing it into Python using pip install PyhthonWebKit which didn't work. I got the message: "No matching distribution found for PythonWebKit".
- **dryscrape**.

Do any of these work?

Comment: I got this list from searching the web but I don't even know if they do the job. I hope that those of you with experience with these libraries can fill me in on this.

Comment: From your question, a few more things are quite unclear: are you looking for a library (to code your own application) – or for some ready-to-use application which you'd just need to configure? Also, the title is misleading – and might tempt the one or other to mark it for closure (we do not cover howtos, manuals, tutorials, and the like).

Comment: You forgot to list Beautiful Soup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). I am unsure if it can do what you want, but it rated way up there with Scrapy, so while you are trying out the others, you can try it too.

Comment: @Mawg BeautifulSoup is a powerful tool to parse HTML. It can be used on top of some of the other choices above when needed.

Answer (score 2):

- **PyQt** is one that might help outworking complex JS stuffed sites.
- **Selenium** is ok, see [an example](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/).
- **DryScrape** is ok, though I've not used it that much.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy when you use [dryscrape python](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). On a Ubuntu PC, installation is as follows:

```
# apt-get install qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev build-essential \
python-lxml python-pip xvfb
```

Usage as follows:

```
Import dryscrape as d
    Import time #for refreshing or waiting for page
    d.start_xvfb() #for using this in linux without Xserver
    br = d.Session() #creating new session
    br.visit('<Any Url>') #for open the page
    Input = br.at_xpath('//*[@name="email"]') #for find input
    Input.set('<input value>')
    Input.form().submit() #for submit
    time.sleep(5) #wait for page load
```

This works fine on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can do anything what user can do in a browser, in a cross-browser way. It is W3C standard for browser automation, and **learning Selenium is good skill to have** for your career (beyond this web-scraping project).

It is widely used for test automation of web-based applications.